# Why obj.a = ( obj.a || [] ).push( 10 ) makes obj.a as type number

Tags: javascript

I am trying to push a value to a property of an array like below

```
 var obj = {};
 obj.a = (obj.a || []).push(10);
 console.log( typeof obj.a ); // Returning number
```

How can correct this to keep obj.a as an array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because [`.push` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the new length of the array:

> Returns
>   The new length property of the object upon which the method was called.

You can do:

```
(obj.a || (obj.a = [])).push(10);
```

Comment: Error if I am trying above like `obj.a = (obj.a || obj.a = []).push(10);` ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Comment: Oh, I guess you need one more set of parenthesis. The whole line ist just `(obj.a || (obj.a = [])).push(10);`. Drop the assignment at the beginning, you are moving the assignment inside.

Comment: Then you must have an error somewhere else because it works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/gX8JD/.